# How to fix the error of align

Tags: errors

Actually I am trying too much but I am not able to fix the error after running: Any help is appreciated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}  
    (f_{xy},f_{yz}) _{[w]}&=[f_{xy},z] - [x, f_{yz}]\\
                                         &=[[x,y]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v v ,z ] - [x ,[y,z] -\sum\alpha_{yz}^v v ]\\
                                         &=[[x,y,z]]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v [v,z] - [x,[y,z]] + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v [x,v]\\
\text{Using Jacobi's identity this equals}
                                         &=[[x,z],y] - \sum\alpha_{xy}^v ([v,z] - \sum \alpha_{vz}^u u)\\
                                         &+ \sum \alpha_{yz}^v ( [x,v] - \sum \alpha_{xv}^u u ) - \sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u u + \sum     \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{xv}^u u\\
                                        &= [[x,z] - \sum \alpha_{xz}^v v , y ] + \sum \alpha_{xz}^v ([v,y] - \sum \alpha_{vy}^u u)\\
                                        &-\sum \alpha_{xy}^v f_{vz} + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v f_{xv}\\
                                        & -\sum_{u} (\sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{vx}^u + \sum \alpha_{zx}^v \alpha_{vy}^u) u
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The above makes no error (if made into a test document), if you mean that you would like a different output it is best to say what output you would like

Comment: Maybe, you want `\intertext` instead of `\text`.

Comment: the error is  Missing \begin{document}. but I put it at the first of article!

Comment: If you get an error you need to post the test file that produces the error, and show the exact error that you get in a code section in the question.

Comment: Error messages are important for debugging. If it is the first line, then a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) could be causing this. Save the file as UTF-8 without BOM then.

Comment: You mean I must select "reload using selected encoding"? the encoding now is UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code works fine, but it seems that you looking for `intertext` as [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) suggest in his comment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
(f_{xy},f_{yz}) _{[w]}&=[f_{xy},z] - [x, f_{yz}]\\
         &=[[x,y]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v v ,z ] - [x ,[y,z] -\sum\alpha_{yz}^v v ]\\
         &=[[x,y,z]]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v [v,z] - [x,[y,z]] + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v [x,v]
\intertext{Using Jacobi's identity this equals:}
    &=[[x,z],y] - \sum\alpha_{xy}^v ([v,z] - \sum \alpha_{vz}^u u)\\
    &+ \sum \alpha_{yz}^v ( [x,v] - \sum \alpha_{xv}^u u ) - \sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u u + \sum     \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{xv}^u u\\
    &= [[x,z] - \sum \alpha_{xz}^v v , y ] + \sum \alpha_{xz}^v ([v,y] - \sum \alpha_{vy}^u u)\\
    &-\sum \alpha_{xy}^v f_{vz} + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v f_{xv}\\
    & -\sum_{u} (\sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{vx}^u + \sum \alpha_{zx}^v \alpha_{vy}^u) u
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

however, i would write this equations as follows:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % <--- instead of `amsmath`, it define `multlined` environment

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
(f_{xy},f_{yz}) _{[w]}&=[f_{xy},z] - [x, f_{yz}]\\
     & = \Bigl[[x,y]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v v ,z \Bigr]
        - \Bigl[x ,[y,z] -\sum\alpha_{yz}^v v \Bigr]\\
     & = [x,y,z] - \sum \alpha_{xy}^v [v,z] - \bigl[x,[y,z]\bigr] + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v [x,v]
\intertext{Using Jacobi's identity this equals:}
(f_{xy},f_{yz})_{[w]}
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\linewidth]
        \bigl[[x,z],y\bigr] - \sum\alpha_{xy}^v \Bigl([v,z] - \sum \alpha_{vz}^u u\Bigr)\\
        + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v 
        \Bigl( [x,v] - \sum \alpha_{xv}^u u \Bigr) - \sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u u + \sum     \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{xv}^u u
        \end{multlined}    \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\linewidth]
        \Bigl[[x,z] - \sum \alpha_{xz}^v v , y \Bigr] \\
            + \sum \alpha_{xz}^v \left([v,y] - \sum \alpha_{vy}^u u\right) %\\
        -\sum \alpha_{xy}^v f_{vz} + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v f_{xv}  \\
        -\sum_{u} \Bigl(\sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{vx}^u + \sum \alpha_{zx}^v \alpha_{vy}^u\Bigr) u
        \end{multlined}     
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suspens, who gessed where the mysterious error is ?

Comment: Actually after running I get error 88

Comment: not in my computer. this error not arise from code which you show in your question. please test both mine codes, if they compile without errors and warnings.

Answer (score 3):

A variant, with the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`, and the optional spacing argument of `\intertext` (defined in `nccmath`), and some delimiters size improvements:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
(f_{xy},f_{yz}) _{[w]}&=[f_{xy},z] - [x, f_{yz}]\\
         &=\bigl[[x,y]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v v ,z \bigr] - \bigl[x ,[y,z] -\sum\alpha_{yz}^v v \bigr]\\
         &=\bigl[[x,y,z]\bigr]- \sum \alpha_{xy}^v [v,z] - \bigl[x,[y,z]\bigr] + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v [x,v]
\intertext[0.5ex]{Using Jacobi's identity this equals:}
 &=\begin{multlined}[t]{}
 \bigl[[x,z],y\bigr] - \sum\alpha_{xy}^v ([v,z] - \sum \alpha_{vz}^u u)\\
 + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v\bigl( [x,v] - \sum \alpha_{xv}^u u \bigr) - \sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u u + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{xv}^u u
 \end{multlined}\\
 &= \begin{multlined}[t]{}%
 \bigl[[x,z] - \sum \alpha_{xz}^v v , y \bigr] + \sum \alpha_{xz}^v \bigl([v,y] - \sum \alpha_{vy}^u u\bigr)\\
 -\sum \alpha_{xy}^v f_{vz} + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v f_{xv}\\
 -\sum_{u} \Bigl(\sum \alpha_{xy}^v \alpha_{vz}^u + \sum \alpha_{yz}^v \alpha_{vx}^u + \sum \alpha_{zx}^v \alpha_{vy}^u\Bigr) u
 \end{multlined}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\intertext[o0.5ex]{...}` defined in `nccmath`. i was'nt aware for  it. similarly can be space reduced by use `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`

Comment: I am using TEXworks, In the tab of errors I see"Errors: 1, Warnings: 0, Bad boxes: 0"

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, I tried `\shortintertext` first, but found it too tight in this context (due to the many `\sum`s ).

Comment: @user118746: An error  with this very code, and nothing more?